# is there a static task in c++

Tags: c++, static, task

Is there a static task in function in C++?

I mean, is there a way, without using a boolean variable, or checking if a variable is empty, to execute one task when a function is called for the first time, and in another call does not execute that task?

Like this:

```
class array 
{
    int array[10];
public :
    int func()
    {
        static for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            array[i] = i;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
```

Considering this code, when we call `func()` for first time, it assigns the array only one time. And when we call `func()` another time, that only prints the array.

Comment: You may want something from the standard `<algorithm>` header  files.

Comment: There is also the pattern of using a `static bool` flag.  Initialize to false.  If the value is `false`, execute the first `for` statement, then set the flag to "true".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) (yes, it uses a variable to maintain state).

Otherwise, move your task logic into a function or lambda that can be used to initialize a local `static` variable (so again, using a variable to maintain state).

---

However, note that your `array[]` is an instance member, and your `func()` is an instance method. Do you really want your `array[]` to be initialized one time *ever*? If you create multiple instances of your class, only the 1st instance will get initialized, but subsequent instances will not, leading to *undefined behavior*.

It sounds more like you should be initializing the `array[]` in your class's *constructor* instead, eg:

```
class array
{
    int m_array[10];
public:
    array()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            m_array[i] = i;
    }

    void func() const
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
           cout << m_array[i] << endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are various ways:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

static constexpr auto compile_time_initialization()
{
    std::array<int, 10> const_array{};
    for (int n = 0; n < static_cast<int>(const_array.size()); ++n)
    {
        const_array[n] = n;
    }
    return const_array;
}

auto func()
{
    // use a lambda to initialize static only once
    static auto arr = []
    {
        std::cout << "first time only.\n";
        std::array<int, 10> lambda_arr{};
        for (int n = 0ul; n < static_cast<int>(lambda_arr.size()); ++n)
        {
            lambda_arr[n] = n;
        }
        return lambda_arr;
    }();

    std::cout << "every time\n";
    return arr;
}


int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        auto arr = func();
        
        for (const int value : arr) std::cout << value << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    //or compile time initialed
    std::cout << "compile time init\n";
    constexpr auto arr = compile_time_initialization();
    for (const int value : arr) std::cout << value << " ";

    return 0;
}
```